# "null" name is given to both folder and file when sinking data from Orion to Cosmos using Cygnus

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus, cosmos, fiware-cosmos

I have an issue related to ngsi2cosmos data flow. Everything works fine when persisting the information received in Orion into the public instance of Cosmos, but the destination folder and file name are both "null".

Simple test as follows:

- I create of a brand new NGSIEntity with these headers added: Fiware-Service: myservice & Fiware-ServicePath: /my
- I add a new subscription with Cygnus as the reference endpoint.
- I send an update to previously created NGSIEntity

When I check my user space in Cosmos I check that the following route has been created: /user/myuser/myservice/null/null.txt

File content is OK, every updated info in Orion has been correctly sinked into it. The problem is with folder and file names. 
I can't make it work properly. Isn't it supposed to get entityId and entityType for folder and file naming?

Component versions:

- Orion version: contextBroker-0.19.0-1.x86_64
- Cygnus version: cygnus-0.5-91.g3eb100e.x86_64
- Cosmos: global instance

Cygnus conf file:

```
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = hdfs-sink 
cygnusagent.channels = hdfs-channel

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = hdfs-channel
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default organization (organization semantic depend on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_organization = org42
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
# Management interface port (FIXME: temporal location for this parameter)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.management_port = 8081
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts
# Timestamp interceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# Destination extractor interceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.de.type = es.tid.fiware.fiwreconnectors.cygnus.interceptors.DestinationExtractor$Builder
# Matching table for the destination extractor interceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.de.matching_table = matching_table.conf

# ============================================
# OrionHDFSSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = hdfs-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.sinks.OrionHDFSSink
# Comma-separated list of FQDN/IP address regarding the Cosmos Namenode endpoints
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_host = 130.206.80.46
# port of the Cosmos service listening for persistence operations; 14000 for httpfs, 50070 for webhdfs and free choice for inifinty
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_port = 14000
# default username allowed to write in HDFS
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_default_username = myuser
# default password for the default username
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.cosmos_default_password = mypassword
# HDFS backend type (webhdfs, httpfs or infinity)
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_api = httpfs
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.attr_persistence = column
# prefix for the database and table names, empty if no prefix is desired
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.naming_prefix =
# Hive FQDN/IP address of the Hive server
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_host = 130.206.80.46
# Hive port for Hive external table provisioning
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_port = 10000

#=============================================
# hdfs-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Comment: Can you, please, edit your question with some relevant logs? (if they are large, try using a Github gist https://gist.github.com/). I would need them to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should configure the matching_table of cygnus to define the path and file name.

You have that file in the same path of Cygnus agent conf file.

You can follow the next example:

```
# integer id|comma-separated fields|regex to be applied to the fields concatenation|destination|dataset
#
# The available "dictionary" of fields is:
#  - entitydId
#  - entityType
#  - servicePath

1|entityId,entityType|Room\.(\d*)Room|numeric_rooms|rooms
```

Comment: This could be, in fact, one of the reasons. I would suggest to check the existence of `/usr/cygnus/conf/matching_table.conf` (not a template but an instance of it) and try to delete/comment any example rule there may exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 

The file was missing and had to create it manually but couldn't get it work (I did this before posting this question).

I tried updating cygnus but the updating process doesn't also work as excpected due to /usr/cygnus directory is removed in the process (luckily i made a backup first).

I will try on a brand new instance and installing orion & cygnus manually as I've checked that versions in orion-psb-image-R4.2 of orion and cygnus are both out of date and that could be also a reason for the error.

Comment: Yes, before Cygnus 0.6.0 there was an error on the RPM that avoids the upgrade by simply doing `yum instal cygnus`. I'll recommend you to read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310111/oauth2-in-cygnus/31312196#31312196. There you will find how to upgrade to Cygnus 0.8.2 and also how to perform authentication/authorization through OAuth2.