# Use cygnus Cosmos with oAuth

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus, fiware-cosmos

I received an email that says that we must now use OAuth to use cosmos.

Is the old behavior is maintained ?, ie, without using oauth?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 will be the only authentication and authorization mechanism supported for WebHDFS, since it is (or should be) an standard for all APIs in FIWARE. If you are using the API, the change is as simple as adding the token as a Http header. If you are using Cygnus, simply upgrade to 0.8.2 (it is always a good practice to upgrade to the latest version) and configure the `oauth2_token` parameter. You have all the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310111/oauth2-in-cygnus/31312196#31312196).